# Can a stray kitten eat eggs?

Tags: cats, health, feeding, safety, strays

I have many stray cats around, and there's this stray kitten I am feeding whenever I can. Is it safe to feed her boiled eggs a few times a week?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can feed eggs to cats but try to limit the amount to two eggs per week.

link https://www.catster.com/lifestyle/cat-health-can-cats-eat-eggs-ask-a-vet-food-tips

If you feed eggs you need to be sure they are boiled to kill the bacteria comonly found in eggs.

Raw eggs contain a substanse that will stop b-vitamins beeing absorbed by cats and dogs so they might get a lack of b-vitamins if you feed a lot of raw eggs(the risk for this is low)if the eggs are boiled this is not a problem.

Only use egg as a suplement you need to feed the kitten other types of food too.

There is a risk the kitten might get an upset stomach when you feed eggs atleast in the beginning so start slow.

Answer (score -1):

I would advice against feeding the kitten, not because it might not tolerate the food very well, but because you teach it to beg or wait to be fed instead of seeking it's own food. You take over the responsibility for this cat as if you had adopted it.

1. What happens to the cat if you cannot feed it anymore, maybe because you moved away or for medical reasons? The cat will suffer from hunger because it never had to hunt for all it's food before.
2. Other cats might notice the food. Before you know it, you're feeding a second cat, then a third and so forth. If you don't feed all of them, they might start fighting over the food.
3. A well-fed cat will have babies. These babies will be strays, just like their mother. If you feed them, they will have more babies... You actually want to help a stray cat, but in the end you let more stray cats be born who will suffer.

You see, it's actually best not to give stray cats any food at all. If you want to, you can give the kitten some small treats, but not enough food to feed it for a day.

The best solution of all would be to donate money to an animal welfare organization that spayes and neuters stray cats so they cannot give birth anymore.

Comment: While I somewhat agree with your point about taking over responsibility, that kinda deviates from the original question. OP wasn't asking whether it's moral to feed stray cats. It was whether a kitten who's in the wild can eat eggs and not get sick.

Comment: I live in middle-east and in my neighborhood the green bin are taken out every morning, strays find food there whenever. Idk hunting, I saw stray cat family eating roaches, so not much facility. They beg for food when they are hungry, the ones in my building is cat family she never meows alot for food, the kittens also quiet, they appreciate the handouts when I’m around. Neighbors sometime leave food out too but it’s not cat-friendly, like pancakes or something, they don’t eat. In very hot climate a little food and some water go along way for the stray city cats. Thank you for sincere advice